# other worksheet format gets ruined using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to python, I am trying to write a very simple python script that will clean my excel file. The problem is that, when I run the code, the formatting of cells on other sheet(Sheet2) that is not in anyway related to the previous sheet (that the code modifies) gets ruined. i am using a portable version of WinPython 3.4.4.

Below, I have this script that clears the contents of Sheet1:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, workbook
wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sh = wb['Sheet1']

for row in sh['B1:C10']:
for cell in row:
    print(cell.value)
    cell.value = None

wb.save('sample.xlsx')
```

Thank you in advance.

***EDIT***
Sorry if my question was confusing. Please see the link for sample files.

Thank you.

[Sample file before and after running the python script](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b7d2cd1cc44d37f661ebc4b0c02ae1e920180904085221/75fe1c24879103f8f1862dfd93937de620180904085221/a1fb15)

---

Hi Charlie,

Thanks for checking on my post. From the attached sample files, you will see that in sample before.xlsx Sheet2 ‘A2’, it has 12:00:00 AM and Sheet4 E, G and H columns have borders. After running the above script, we now have the sample after.xlsx, Sheet 1 and 2 ‘A2 ‘ now has -1 value and Sheet 4 E, G and H Columns do not have borders. I have been trying to play around with this since the day I posted this question but the only thing that I could do is to just format the cells again. But still, my question is, why does this simple code affect the other sheet when it is only intended to modify a specific sheet which is Sheet1.

Comment: This code does not describe the problem you are experiencing. Please be explicit about what exactly gets ruined and, preferably provide a file.

Comment: Posting files doesn't really help.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I edited the original question as my answer is too long for posting as comment. Thanks again.